# how to add AsyncTask class in fragment

Tags: android, android-asynctask, android-fragmentactivity

hi am new to android how to add `asynctask` class in fragment , i have error in `new ProgressTask().execute();` i would like to add progress bar on the screen..

here is my code

```
@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
        Bundle savedInstanceState) {

    View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_zudioz, container, false);
    setHasOptionsMenu(true);


    webView = (WebView)rootView.findViewById(R.id.webView1);
    bar = (ProgressBar) rootView.findViewById(R.id.progressBar);
    new ProgressTask().execute();
    private class ProgressTask extends AsyncTask <Void,Void,Void>{
        @Override
        protected void onPreExecute(){
            bar.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        }

        @Override
        protected Void doInBackground(Void... arg0) {   
               //my stuff is here
        }

        @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(Void result) {
              bar.setVisibility(View.GONE);
        }
    }

    webView.loadUrl("http://www.zudioz.com");
    webView.getSettings().setSupportZoom(true);
    webView.getSettings().setBuiltInZoomControls(true);
    webView.setScrollBarStyle(WebView.SCROLLBARS_OUTSIDE_OVERLAY);
    webView.setScrollbarFadingEnabled(true);
    webView.getSettings().setLoadsImagesAutomatically(true);
    webView.getSettings().setDomStorageEnabled(true);
    webView.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient());           
    webView.getSettings().setAllowFileAccess(true); 
    webView.getSettings().setDomStorageEnabled(true);
    webView.getSettings().setAppCacheEnabled(true);
    webView.getSettings().setAppCacheMaxSize(1024*1024*8);                              
    return rootView;
}
```

Comment: where is your asynctask class?

Comment: @Raghunandan i did'n create i have error in new progresstask().execute();

Comment: refer the docs http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/AsyncTask.html . make asynctask an inner class of your fragment

Comment: @ibu what errors you are getting? Include more detail about error

Comment: Can you show your `new ProgressTask()` code ?

Comment: @PareshMayani when i add asynctask, class name error(Illegal modifier for the local class ProgressTask; only abstract or final is permitted)

Comment: @ibu you need to check the docs and know more about asynctask

Comment: @ibu check my answer and also read docs to make your AsyncTask funda clear

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try out as below:

```
class ProgressTask extends AsyncTask<String, Integer, String> {

        @Override
        protected void onPreExecute() {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            super.onPreExecute();
                    progressDialog = new ProgressDialog(getActivity());
            progressDialog .setMessage("Loading...");
            progressDialog .setCancelable(false);
            progressDialog .show();
        }

        @Override
        protected String doInBackground(String... params) {
            return string;
        }

        @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(String result) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            super.onPostExecute(result);
            progressDialog.dismiss();
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Instead of Progress Bar, you can write Like this:

```
ProgressDialog progressDialog = new ProgressDialog(getActivity());
progressDialog.setMessage("Loading...");
progressDialog.show();
```

in your Async task's onPreExecute()

Answer (score 0):

Mistake you did is you have created ProgressTask inside `onCreateView()`, instead create it outside `onCreateView()` (let's say class level) and execute it inside `onCreateView()` by using `execute()` method of AsyncTask.

For example:

```
@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
        Bundle savedInstanceState) {

    View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_zudioz, container, false);
    setHasOptionsMenu(true);


    webView = (WebView)rootView.findViewById(R.id.webView1);
    bar = (ProgressBar) rootView.findViewById(R.id.progressBar);
    new ProgressTask().execute();
    ....
    ....
}

 private class ProgressTask extends AsyncTask <Void,Void,Void>{
        @Override
        protected void onPreExecute(){
            bar.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        }

        @Override
        protected void doInBackground(Void... arg0) {   
               //my stuff is here
        }

        @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(Void result) {
              bar.setVisibility(View.GONE);
        }
    }
```

Comment: @ibu yes that's one more mistake in your code, change it to `void`